# How to transfer data from different fragments in tabLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a problem passing the selected Item of my ListView to another fragment.

I have a TabbedActivity with 2 tabs. 1st is called **OngletCours** and the 2nd is called **OngletNotes**.

I'm getting an error while passing the Item I clicked on.

I have tried the whole weekend but without sucess to transfer the Item I clicked on to the 2nd tab/fragment.

Here is the code from my 1st Fragment/Tab **OngletCours** (I'm only showing you the setOnItemClickListener :

```
     l1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            OngletNotes fragment = ((Onglets)getActivity()).getOngletNotes();

            if(fragment == null) {
                fragment = OngletNotes.newInstance();
            }
            //récupération de la position convertie en String de l'item que j'ai choisi
            String item = l1.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("Item",item);

            fragment.setArguments(args);

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            ((Onglets)getActivity()).goToFragment(1);
        }

    });
```

My 2nd tab/Fragment **OngletNotes** looks like this :

```
public class OngletNotes extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ongletnotes, container, false);
    //where i want to insert the selectedItem
    TextView Cours = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.TVCours);

    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    String cours="";
    //ERROR !
    cours = bundle.getString("Item");
    //Retrieve the value
    Cours.setText(cours);

    return rootView;
}

public static OngletNotes newInstance() {
    OngletNotes fragment = new OngletNotes();
    // put values which you want to pass to fragment
    // Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

I have the following error :

> 03-06 12:48:13.959 1033-1033/com.example.dasilvadd.students E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                     at com.example.dasilvadd.students.OngletNotes.onCreateView(OngletNotes.java:23)

Line 23 is the following one :

> Bundle bundle=getArguments();

Please help me solving this, I really need to advance in my project. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Don't pass the data like above.. You are using tab, so it will should need PagerAdapter and it respective function Offscreenpagelimit. So the second fragmenty OngletNotes will not receive data in OnCreateView...

Comment: Oh thank your for the advice. But how do I do it ? I mean the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shared preferences, create a shared preference in OngletCours then read from in OngletNotes. there is a single instance of this class that all clients share , so in this case it makes sense.Go to this link to refresh it code syntax.https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

hey just remember this for future purposes, serialize your data whenever your store it. a great library is gson. Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.Just something to think about still.

Comment: well the tutorial on the site i provided is pretty good. Use it , 100% works.

Comment: I create a shared preferences in my ClickListener ? And I can delete all the code I had before and replace it by all the methodes of SharedPreference?

Comment: so create a shared preference in your click listener store the string, then in the other fragment read from it, get the string data. that's all really.

Comment: The problem is that I have a TabbedActivity, so I want to swap to the 2nd tab (OngletNotes) and I want that the Item selected is transfered with the sharedPreferences, but instead, I'm getting the content of my 2nd tab on my 1st, and not swapping, do you know how to solve ?

Comment: so just me confirm, the shared preference does work but it does not swap any data.?

Comment: Yes. But i've changed something and now I'm able to swap to the 2nd tab, but the data is not transfered. I Inserted the following code `TextView Cours = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.TVCours);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String cours = sharedPref.getString("Item",null);
        Cours.setText(cours);` in OnCreateView of my 2nd Tab (OngletNotes)

Comment: String cours = sharedPref.getString("Item",null); to String cours = sharedPref.getString("Item","");

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do it , try upvoting my question so I earn additionall reputation and I can upvote.
Thank you for the advice, I'll think about that in future for sure.

Comment: just another question.. I have 2 items on my ListView. I click once, the item is shown in the 2nd tab, but if I come back to 1st tab and click on the 2nd item, it still shows the first item I clicked..

Comment: because the content is still stored for the first item, either remove or it or over write it.

Comment: And how do I do it ? I wrote `sharedPref.edit().clear().commit();` in OngletNotes but the content of my textView remains ..

Comment: well that's weird it should erase it, show me your code for setting the key value pairs.

Comment: Code inserted in the setOnItemClickListener
            `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                String item = listViewCours.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();                 
                editor.putString("Item",item);
                editor.commit();
                ((Onglets)getActivity()).goToFragment(1);`

Comment: I solved it ! Had to use registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener. Thank you !

Comment: i  recommend you keep a reference to the listener in the instance data of an object that will exist as long as you need the listener. else it will be garbage collected.glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

Use Bundle to send String:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("YourKey", "YourValue");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
```

In onCreateView of the new Fragment:

```
//Retrieve the value
    String value = getArguments().getString("YourKey");
```

i hope it will work for your case

Comment: can you please check the key that u will pass to other fragment is same or not?

eg: "YourKey"

Answer (score 0):

Provide a constructor for your fragment

```
 public OngletNotes () {
        setArguments(new Bundle());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Bundle for transfer data if you have only two framgent in the tab.

I will explain you from the beginning..

For ViewPager you need list of Fragments right. Just like below

```
List<Fragment> fragmentsList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
fragmentsList.add(Fragment1)-->OngletCours
fragmentsList.add(Fragment2)-->OngletNotes
```

You will pass the above list in ViewPagerAdapter.

Have one function in Fragment2 like below

```
 public void getDataFromFragmentOne(String item){
 // Do the mannipulation
 }
```

When the item clicked in FragmentOne Just call the above function like below

> ((OngletNotes)getParentFragment.fragmentsList.get(1)).getDataFromFragmentOne(item)..

The above should work perfectly..Because you are not handling data in onCreateView or onCreate.. Whenever the item is clicked you will pass the data to the secondframent which is already there in viewpager because of offsreenpage limt.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation! But in the future I think I'll have more than two fragment, should I use Bundles or not ?

Answer (score 0):

in Case of kotlin you can create newInstance in fragment;

```
class TeamTwoFragment :Fragment {
   lateinit var eventsX: EventsX
   lateinit var stateList: StateList
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        eventsX = it.getParcelable (EVENT_X)!!
        stateList = it.getParcelable(STATE_LIST)!!
    }

}
fun newInstance(someInt: EventsX, events: StateList): TeamTwoFragment {
    val myFragment = TeamTwoFragment().apply {
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putParcelable(EVENT_X, someInt)
        args.putParcelable(STATE_LIST, events)
        setArguments(args)
    }

    return myFragment
}

 And from tablayout activity or fragments when setup tablayout:
  
 setupViewPager(binding.viewPager,TeamOneFragment().newInstance(eventsX,events))
```